# Getting TimeOutException in selenium due to this unable to switch to third window in IE

Tags: selenium

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out 
waiting for page to load.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11- 
   14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'INGGNED89DP882', ip: '10.197.131.45', os.name: 'Windows 
10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, 
browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, 
platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: 
{browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: 
true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.ensureCleanSession: true, 
ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, 
ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: 
http://localhost:46027/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, 
setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 908d30d6-dc3f-4ac8-a1ca-1ddfc060b716
```

Getting above exception in Internet Explorer Windows 10 , java.version: '1.8.0_60'

Answer (score 0):

try to use the explicit wait based on the condition

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverwait(driver,30);
wait.Until(ExpectedCondtions.VisibilityofemementlocatedBy(yourxpath));
```